# Is it possible to refresh token every hour in AWS Secrets Manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, token, bearer-token, aws-secrets-manager

DOCS:

```
AWS Secrets Manager automatically triggers a rotation this number of days 
after the previous rotation. 
If you ever rotate the secret manually, the rotation interval resets.

You can choose one of the predefined values, 
or choose Custom and then type any number 
between 1 and the maximum value of 365.
```

What about one hour?

Any other services that could help?

Comment: The minimum is 1 day, so no, you can't refresh automatically every 1 hour.

Comment: You could possibly run a lambda function each hour to set new secret value.

Comment: Thanks, @Marcin! Yes, seems to me it is the best idea so far.

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I will provide answer with extra info.

Comment: @Marcin Go for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/11/aws-secrets-manager-rotation-secrets-as-often-as-four-hours/

secrets manager now allows more frequent rotations.  Additionally, this it allows rotation windows to schedule your rotations within

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments.

The minimum automated refresh time of secret is **1 day**. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/rotate-secret.html):

> Secrets Manager schedules the next rotation when the previous one completes. Secrets Manager schedules the date by adding the rotation interval (**number of days**) to the actual date of the last rotation. The service chooses the hour within that **24-hour** date window randomly. The minute is also chosen somewhat randomly, but weighted towards the top of the hour and influenced by a variety of factors that help distribute load.

One way to update the secret each hour would be to use [Scheduled CloudWatch Event rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html). The rule would trigger a **lambda function each hour**, which in turn would set new value of the secret in the AWS Secrets Manager.