# how to update secrets manager secret value from lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-secrets-manager

I have a access token retrieved from an api and its lifetimes is 5 hours. I saw that secrets manager can rotate a secret but minimum rotation time is 1 day. Because of this i thought that i can write a lambda function that works every 5 hours and takes a new token from api and updates secret with this token. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66610124/11902308 mentions that it can be done but i couldn't find any resource about how to update a secret from a lambda function.

Note:
I have multiple task and token is invalid when a new one is generated because of that task have to share it.

Comment: It's no different from updating a secret from any other compute platform. You just write the code in programming language of your choice, using the AWS SDK to call `put_secret_value()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention which AWS SDK you are using, but here is an example for AWS SDK for JS to create or update a Secret.
Additionally, it handles the case for deleted secrets (SecretsManager doesn't delete secrets immediately, it marks them as scheduled for deletion) and restores and updates them.

```js
import { AWSError } from 'aws-sdk';
import SecretsManager, { SecretARNType } from 'aws-sdk/clients/secretsmanager';

const secretsManager = new SecretsManager({ apiVersion: '2017-10-17' });

const putSecret = async (name: string, secret: Record<string, unknown>, secretId?: SecretARNType): Promise<SecretARNType> => {
  try {
    const result = secretId
      ? secretsManager.updateSecret({
          SecretId: secretId,
          SecretString: JSON.stringify(secret),
        })
      : secretsManager.createSecret({
          Name: name,
          SecretString: JSON.stringify(secret),
        });

    const { ARN } = await result.promise();

    if (!ARN) throw new Error(`Error saving secret ${name}`);

    return ARN;
  } catch (error) {
    const awsError = error as AWSError;

    // InvalidRequestException indicates that the secret is scheduled for deletion
    if (awsError.code === 'InvalidRequestException') {
      // restore existng secret
      await secretsManager
        .restoreSecret({
          SecretId: secretId || name,
        })
        .promise();
      // update secret
      const { ARN } = await secretsManager
        .updateSecret({
          SecretId: secretId || name,
          SecretString: JSON.stringify(secret),
        })
        .promise();

      if (!ARN) throw new Error(`Error restoring secret ${name}`);

      return ARN;
    }

    throw error;
  }
};
```

The code is in TypeScript, but should be easily converted into the language of your choice because the AWS SDK functions have the same name in other languages.